# How do I remove Timekpr next from my system its Ubuntu? It says that cant remove virtual packages

Tags: package-management, 20.04, uninstall

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Virtual packages like 'timekpr' can't be removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: How did you install it?

Answer (score 0):

From the [Timekpr](https://mjasnik.gitlab.io/timekpr-next/) docs:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge timekpr-next
```